# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany::$title

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Sorry for bad English at first ) 
I'm new to laravel5 and trying to use polymorphic relations

here is the code

```
class Post extends Model
{


    public function seo()
    {
        return $this->MorphMany('App\Seo' , 'seoable');
    }

}


class Seo extends Model
{
    public function seoble()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

and in the view I try to retrieve post seo data like this

```
$post->seo()->title;
```

here is my DB

```
Schema::create('seos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('keywords');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('og_type');
        $table->string('og_title');
        $table->text('og_description');
        $table->integer('seoable_id');
        $table->string('seoable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

but I got the error

```
Undefined property: 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany::$title (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lblog/resources/views/posts/form.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`$post->seo->first()->title;` or `$post->seo()->get()->first()->title;`

the reason why it doesn't work because the the `seo()` function until now is just a query, you need to execute that query like above

Comment: the same result on both cases Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lblog/resources/views/posts/form.blade.php)

Comment: thats because it's array of items, i edited my answer

Comment: yes its work now thank You, I'm just wondering of the solution , in case of other realtions no need for ->get()->first() , is it specific for polymorphic ?

Comment: for every relation you need to do `get()` but you use `first()` to get the first item in the array it has nothing to do with the relation, more on this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections